# How can you warm up Mars?

Tags: mars, planetary-science, terraforming, solar-system, mars-one

Mars experience extreme temperatures. Highest temperature being 21 degree celsius.
So if we are to terraform mars one day then we first need to warm it up. So any ideas on **how to warm up mars**?

Comment: 21° C seams quite nice to me... yes I know: I should not mix average temperature and maximum temperature. BTT: Before actually warming mars up, you first have to ensure, that a warmed up mars will keep its atmosphere! Due to the lack of a magnetic field and the lower gravity your first priority is not to make it worse. And heating mars up would result in loosing more atmosphere, which makes it even worse. Humanity is an expert in warming up planets, unfortunately. This time we would need an even stronger greenhause gas than CO2 ... maybe large amounts of methane?

Comment: This is very broad, there are studies and books about terraforming Mars. It's hard to see how you're going to get answers.

Comment: @CallMeTom What can we do about the lack of magnetic field?

Comment: You don't need to do anything about it unless you want the atmosphere to outlast your civilization that's capable of terraforming. Solar wind stripping away atmosphere takes a _long_ time.

Comment: Introduce microbes that eat rock and expel gas.  [more info](https://bigthink.com/hard-science/using-bacteria-to-terraform-mars/)

Comment: @Wyck microbes can't just "eat rock and expel gas", the suggestion is chemically absurd. At best, they can use chemosynthesis to extract energy from certain specific minerals. Building an Earthlike atmosphere on Mars requires mostly nitrogen, which simply doesn't exist in large quantities in rocks. The Mars Ecopoiesis Testbed proposal is for growing cyanobacteria to convert CO2 and water to biomass and free oxygen using photosynthesis. This will *consume* atmospheric gases and would be one of the last steps in terraforming, not a method for obtaining atmospheric gases.

Answer (score 7):

Mars is in a thermal equilibrium, where the same amount of energy as received is radiated away.

This leads to two broad categories of strategies.

**1. Increase the amount of illumination.** More energy in means the temperature of the system has to increase until a new equilibrium is reached. As we have no power source even close to the same power as the Sun, this means installing some kind of mirror in space to make more sun light hit Mars.

**2. Decrease the heat loss.** Less energy out means the means the temperature of the system has to increase until a new equilibrium is reached.
Proposed schemes include:

- Dark material covering the surface, reducing direct reflection
- Releasing natural volatiles into the atmosphere to block outbound thermal radiation ("greenhouse effect").
- Release artificial gasses with a much higher greenhouse potential.

These all run into the problem of being very large projects outside our current capability.

Comment: Hmm. Good ideas.

Answer (score 2):

There's no consensus behind a simple solution. In a way, this is good news. We have multiple options, which needn't be mutually exclusive.

Mars has both dry ice and water ice (in the poles and to an unknown extent in the regolith), and each has a greenhouse effect. If Mars could be warmed enough to sublimate the former and melt and partially evaporate the latter, they would provide further radiative forcing. Proposals differ on how to initiate this.

Those focused on warming include importing other greenhouse gases, the [*in situ* production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terraforming_of_Mars#Use_of_fluorine_compounds) of fluorine compounds with especially pronounced greenhouse effects, [mirror-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terraforming_of_Mars#Use_of_orbital_mirrors) increased insolation, [albedo reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terraforming_of_Mars#Albedo_reduction) with photosynthetic organisms, and the detonation of multiple nuclear bombs which has [been critiqued](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5svfhBLJvg0) for its cost, since mirrors continually heat while a bomb does so just once.

There are also aspects of terraforming with other motives noted to have a warming effect. For example, Mars has less water than Earth and negligible elemental oxygen, so we may wish to introduce water and rely on some of it photodissociating with appropriate catalysis. (This [has also been proposed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terraforming#Prospective_targets) for Mercury, Venus and the Moon, and in practice what's delivered may be hydrogen to save on mass, as it can react with local oxides. This is especially applicable to Venus, where hydrogen [can reduce the greenhouse effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terraforming_of_Venus#Introduction_of_hydrogen).) Establishing an ecosystem would also require nitrogen, say from Titan. But the delivery of external matter converts GPE into heat, so the real issue is doing it slowly enough not to overheat the surface, which could cause such matter to escape Mars as a gas, unless it first has a (likely artificial) magnetosphere established.

Then there are aspects of terraforming which may inhibit warming Mars. For example, the consumption of carbon dioxide in photosynthesis to grow food thereby reduces the greenhouse effect. An ecosystem or civilization on Mars may have quite complex weathering effects on its rocks, and hence on how they change the fledgeling atmosphere.

[*Paraterraforming*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terraforming#Paraterraforming) may use these ideas on a smaller scale, if only at first. Most Martian water ice is in its North pole. The North of the surface [is at much lower altitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martian_dichotomy) than the South, so existing water supplies would be confined to the lowlands without substantial infrastructure to distribute it. This likely includes water vapour, so there may be climate disparities during early terraforming.

Comment: Isn't the percentage of atmospheric gas loss trivial over periods as long as tens or even hundreds of thousands of years? Would the introduction of heat (say from atmospheric entry heating of large nitrogen ice balls launched from Titan) change it enough to increase the rate significantly?